# Getting the error while starting react-native project

Tags: react-native, gradlew, react-native-community

I am beginner in react-native. While building my app for android, I am getting this error

```
Task :react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
39 actionable tasks: 39 executed
Note: /home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/toolbar-android/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/toolbarandroid/ReactToolbar.java:107: error: IconImageInfo is not abstract and does not override abstract method getExtras() in HasImageMetadata
  private static class IconImageInfo implements ImageInfo {
                 ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: /home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/toolbar-android/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/toolbarandroid/ReactToolbar.java:107: error: IconImageInfo is not abstract and does not override abstract method getExtras() in HasImageMetadata
  private static class IconImageInfo implements ImageInfo {
                 ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

```
at makeError (/home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/kanhaiya/testapp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

I have already linked `react-native-community/toolbar-android` in my project using `react-native link @react-native-community/toolbar-android`. Still it is giving error.

Answer (score 2):

There are few steps, you can follow up, and see if things are working.

**FIRST WAY:**

```
cd Android && cd ./gradlew clean
```

**Please note:** `./gradlew <follow_by_script_command>` for **MacOS**. For **Windows**, just do `gradlew <follow_by_script_command>`.

If you want to generate a `bundle`, then do this after the above commands:

```
./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
```

**SECOND WAY:**

Possible reason of this error is your RN version might be different from **Android's build.gradle version** which **android/app/build.gradle**. When you create a `react-native` app probably it create android app like:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

Try inspecting your `node_modules` folder, look for `react-native` folder and look for a folder with a number, that numbers are react-native version. For me it's **0.66.4** then update **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.4"
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for answering.But none of them solved my issue. I solved my issue using the info given in this link https://github.com/react-native-toolbar-android/toolbar-android/issues/57#issue-998956857

Answer (score 0):

after running yarn upgrade @react-native-community/toolbar-android@^0.2.1, the problem is gone.If you are using npm then update the package to the latest.Happy Coding :)

Comment: Please add code as code format